# Notation for a reflexive predicate that can also have distinct variables?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

How would you define a predicate $P$ that asserts $P(x,y)$ which can also be reflexive?

The way I did it was:

$\quad$ $I(\exists$ $P.C)=\{x,y \quad | \quad \top \sqsubseteq \exists$ $P.Self$ $\land$ $P(x, y) \}$

I'm trying to state that for some $x$ and $y$, the model can assert $P(x,y)$ but also that $P$ is reflexive.

Is this even valid notation?

Answer (score 1):

As far as notation goes, you can just use $P(x,y)$ ... just because $x$ and $y$ are different variables does not mean that $P$ cannot be reflexive: you can always pick the same object for both $x$ and $y$ if needed.